# Can I put processor with DMI bus to motherboard with QPI bus?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, computer-building, bus

I found out differences of QPI and DMI processors. *Thanks answers for [this question](https://superuser.com/q/692058/327550).*

As I understand, QPI processors (Xeon E5-2xxx series) is used for multi-processor systems.
But I want create one-processor system, and I choose DMI bus CPU and server platform with QPI bus motherboard.

I not found DMI CPU suitable motherboard with LGA2011-3 Socket for this processor, and I not understand:

Will work this configuration, if I not plan to adding second processor?

- **CPU:** [Intel Xeon E5-1650 v4](http://ark.intel.com/products/92994/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-1650-v4-15M-Cache-3_60-GHz) (DMI bus)
- **Server platform:** [Supermicro  7038A-I](https://www.supermicro.com/products/system/tower/7038/SYS-7038A-i.cfm) (QPI bus)

Comment: Thanks, I found one-processor server [Supermicro 5038A-I](https://www.supermicro.com/products/system/tower/5038/sys-5038a-i.cfm) with [X10SRA](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X10SRA.cfm) motherboard, it support Xeon E5-1xxx and E5-2xxx processors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DMI is used by processors to connect the northbridge (or what used to be northbridge) to the PCH (southbridge).

QPI is used to connect the processors to the northbridge.

That means, QPI will be used in your case to access the RAM, secondary CPU (if you add one) and PCI-E lanes.

There is a clear **incompatibility** issue in your situation. E5-1650 series were designed as single socket CPUs. The Supermicro 7038A-I MB in incompatible with that.

Answer (score 0):

Technical specifications of target server says:
CPU Intel® Xeon® processor E5-2600 v4†/ v3 family (up to 160W TDP)
Dual Socket R3 (LGA 2011)

the processor Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-1650 v4 (15M Cache, 3.60 GHz) is designed for 1 socket system only and it hasn't support by motherboard of your server

and if you see specs on cpu:
Scalability - 1S Only